# Java collection to allow adding and removing while iterating

Tags: java, collections, frameworks, concurrent-collections

I am interested if there is any framework that implements a collection that would have the following behavior.

---

Suppose it initially contains: [1, 2, 3]

- I iterate it (using an iterator) and reach element 2, now I add 4 to the end (the collection will now be [1, 2, 3, 4]).
- now I create a new iterator and iterate the collection, resulting in [1, 2, 3, 4]
- I continue iterating with the first iterator and it will give me just 3 and return
- now resetting the first iterator will give me [1, 2, 3, 4] (similar to creating a new one).

Same should apply for removal of elements. If I remove 3 instead of adding, the second iterator should give me [1, 2] while the first one will still give me 3 and the end.

---

So when I get and iterator I want it to give me the collection I had when I created the iterator (even if I iterate it later, on I iterate a bit and continue later), when I reset the iterator, it gets garbage collected it will update to the latest versions and I should be able to have multiple iterator instances created at different times that will give different versions depending on the contents of the array when the iterator was created.

I would need it to work well with multiple threads and preferable have an efficient implementation.

Does anyone know of any implementation of such a collection, or do I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe looks very similar to how [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) works:

- once you start iterating, you can change the collection (including from another thread) without affecting the iteration
- if you create a new iterator it will be based on the collection at the creation time
- it is thread safe

Simple example below with the following output:

> Iterator 1 - 1
>   4 has been added
>   Iterator 2 - 1
>   Iterator 2 - 2
>   Iterator 2 - 3
>   Iterator 2 - 4
>   Iterator 1 - 2
>   Iterator 1 - 3

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final List<Integer> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (Integer i : list) {
                System.out.println("Iterator 1 - " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }).start();
    Thread.sleep(10);
    list.add(4);
    System.out.println("4 has been added");
    for (Integer i : list) {
        System.out.println("Iterator 2 - " + i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it create a new copy of the collection on change (internally)? Or is it implemented in a more efficient manner?

Comment: Yes as described in the javadoc: "all mutative operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array."

Comment: The behavior looks like what I need. But the collection is going to have quite a few items in it. Iterators are created frequently on it, but I believe changes are rarer (so copies on change might not incur too much performance loss).

Comment: @Razvi in which case you should be fine. You can always find something if the performance you get does not match your expectations.

Answer (score 7):

[`java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) will behave like this, except that no Java collection has "resetting" of iterators -- but getting a new iterator instead of resetting has the effect you request here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ImmutableCollections](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) from the guava library.

> The returned ImmutableList is frequently -- not always, but frequently
>   -- a constant-overhead view, rather than an explicit copy. That said, it's often smarter than your average List -- for example, it'll use
>   the efficient contains methods of the backing collection.

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of [`java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

*According documentation:*

> A thread-safe variant of ArrayList in which all mutative operations
>   (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the
>   underlying array.

**Its costly, but thread safe.**

> This is ordinarily too costly, but may be more efficient than
>   alternatives when traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations, and
>   is useful when you cannot or don't want to synchronize traversals, yet
>   need to preclude interference among concurrent threads. The "snapshot"
>   style iterator method uses a reference to the state of the array at
>   the point that the iterator was created.

As the iteration occurs over a kind of snapshot, the operations (`remove`, `set`, and `add`) on `Iterator` itself are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

javolution have threadsafe FastMap